# "While not " not working with float?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to get it so if you input a letter / non-number, you get the "Please insert a numerical value for ..." but it doesn't seem to be working...

```
 #This allows for the user to input the values of the variables
    a = float(raw_input ("Please insert a numerical value for a: "))
    while not (a.isdigit()):
        a = float(raw_input ("Please insert a numerical value for a: "))
    print ("Well done.")

    b = float(raw_input ("Please insert a numerical value for b: "))
    while not (b.isdigit()):
        b = float(raw_input ("Please insert a numerical value for b: "))
    print ("Well done.")

    c = float(raw_input ("Please insert a numerical value for c: "))
    while not (b.isdigit()):
        c = float(raw_input ("Please insert a numerical value for c: "))
    print ("Well done.")
```

Comment: It doesn't *seem* to be working? What happens? Do you get an error message? (I get a very specific error message.)

Comment: When I put in a letter:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\XXX\Downloads\test.py", line 10, in <module>
    a = float(raw_input ("Please insert a numerical value for a: "))
ValueError: could not convert string to float: a


and when I put in a number:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\XXX\Downloads\test.py", line 11, in <module>
    while not (a.isdigit()):
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'isdigit'

Comment: Ok. The important part of that is `AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'isdigit'` and would have been helpful to include directly in your question.

Comment: The traceback is straight forward. If it can't convert to a `float`, the `ValueError` is raised. The `AttributeError` is straightforward. `float`s don't have an `isdigit()` method.

Comment: Thank you all for answers, I think I get it now :)

Answer (score 2):

`isdigit()` is for strings. You're using floats, and casting can raise a `ValueError`. So do this:

```
while True:
    try:
        c = float(raw_input("Enter a numerical value")
        break
    except ValueError:
        pass
```

Answer (score 1):

`isdigit()` is a method for strings, you are using a float here.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `isdigit()` on a `float` object. Basically, you need to call `isdigit()` before calling `float()` on your input string. Here is how I might write one of your loops:

```
while True:
    s = raw_input ("Please insert a numerical value for a: ")
    try:
        a = float(s)
        break
    except ValueError:
        print "Please enter a numeric value."
print ("Well done.")
```

Comment: `isdigit()` only returns True if the string is an integer. If there is a floating point, it return false. ex: `"15.5".isdigit()` returns False.

Comment: @Zizouz212: Well that's true. That's one reason I wouldn't use `isdigit()` anyway (it also only works for *positive* integers, because the negative sign is not a digit either). My example doesn't need it.

Answer (score -1):

there is not an error regarding while loop but the error is on isdigit() function which is for strings... so first u type cast it into string then check it using while funtion